# Error While Creating Python Extension in C

Tags: python, c, cpython

So, I am trying to use c to create a basic extension for python.  After running the 'build' command with the setup.py file, I got an error that said

```
helloworld.c(14):  error C2099: initializer is not a constant
```

Below is my code for the file 'helloworld.c'...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject* helloworld(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {
    printf("Hello World");
    return Py_None;
}

static PyMethodDef myMethods[] = {
    { "helloworld", helloworld, METH_NOARGS, "Prints Hello World" },
    { NULL, NULL, 0, NULL }
};

static struct PyMethodDef myModule = {
    PyMethodDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "myModule",
    "Test Module",
    -1,
    myMethods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_myModule(void) {
    return PyModule_Create(&myModule);
}
```

And here is my 'setup.py' file...

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup(name = "myModule", version = '1.0', \
    ext_modules = [Extension('myModule', ['helloworld.c'])])
```

Why is this error being caused, and how can I fix it?  Thanks.

Comment: In your module struct, you've used `PyMethodDef` and `PyMethodDef_HEAD_INIT` instead of `PyModuleDef` and `PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT`. Is that just a simple typo, or do you need an explanation?

Comment: I'm new to this so an explanation would be great!

Comment: OK, I've written an answer; let me know if it doesn't explain things clearly enough. Meanwhile, have you considered using Cython, or one of the nice wrappers C or C++ wrappers that make all this boilerplate a lot less tedious and harder to get wrong? I think the [PyPA docs](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-binary-extensions/) go into some of the options.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is pretty simple. You've used the wrong type, `struct PyMethodDef` instead of `struct PyModuleDef`, for your module instance, and  you've also used a non-existent identifier `PyMethodDef_HEAD_INIT` instead of `PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT` to initialize its first element.

I'm not sure why your compiler is telling you that this is not a constant initializer instead of telling you that it doesn't exist at all (both clang and gcc do that for me, and I don't remember MSVC's error messages being that bad…), but that is the real problem: there is no such thing as `PyMethodDef_HEAD_INIT`.

If you fix both of those:

```
static struct PyModuleDef myModule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "myModule",
    "Test Module",
    -1,
    myMethods
};
```

… it builds:

```
$ python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
building 'myModule' extension
/usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c helloworld.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/helloworld.o
/usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/helloworld.o -o /Users/abarnert/src/hellopy/myModule.cpython-36m-darwin.so
```

… and, although you probably wanted to give it a name like `helloworld` or `_helloworld` instead of `myModule`, it works:

```
$ python3
>>> import myModule
>>> myModule.helloworld()
Hello World>>>
```

(You probably wanted a `\n` at the end of that string, too.)